# SQL UPDATE Statement in excel VBA not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this code to update database with SQL but it is not working

```
Call Connect_to_db
strSQL = "UPDATE StockTable " & _
 "SET StockTable.Selected = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("g" & x) & "' " & _
 "WHERE OwnerName = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("a" & x) & WHERE OwnerShipMethod = Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("b" & g) & WHERE StockName = Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("c" & g) & WHERE Quantity = Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("d" & g)  "' "
cn.Execute strSQL
Call Close_db
```

Comment: _...it is not working_ means what? Do you get any errors? Please post them! And BTW: You forgot lots of single and double quotes and AND/OR(?) in your where clause!

Answer (score 0):

This is your code as posted, but then with some extra linebreaks and outlining. Maybe you can spot the obvious errors yourself better now?

```
Call Connect_to_db
strSQL = "UPDATE StockTable " & _
         "SET StockTable.Selected = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("g" & x) & "' " & _
         "WHERE OwnerName = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("a" & x) & _
          WHERE OwnerShipMethod =     Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("b" & g) & _
          WHERE StockName = Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("c" & g) & _
          WHERE Quantity = Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("d" & g)  "' "
cn.Execute strSQL
Call Close_db
```

In this version I have changed the extra `WHERE` clauses to `AND`, and I haev added some obviously missing " and '.

```
Call Connect_to_db
strSQL = "UPDATE StockTable " & _
         "SET StockTable.Selected = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("g" & x) & "' " & _
         "WHERE OwnerName = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("a" & x) & "' " & _
         "AND OwnerShipMethod = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("b" & g) & "' " & _
         "AND StockName = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("c" & g) & "' " & _
         "AND Quantity = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("d" & g) & "' "
cn.Execute strSQL
Call Close_db
```

I guess this shoudl work better allready, if it doesn't please tell us *what* is not working, *what* error messages, if any, you are getting, *and* please show the actual content of strSQL before yuo execute it. That string should contain a straightforward SQL statement, but there might be errors in it, so have a look at that and, if necessary, post it for us to look at :)

Comment: I used the second code and gave me the error message " Data type mismatch in criteria expression "

Comment: well, since _we_ know _nothing_ about your data types, you might be better positioned to solve that error than we are :)